# Changing default width of blocks in LaTeX Beamer

Tags: latex, pdflatex, presentation, beamer

I use a custom Beamer theme for my presentations. In my presentations I'd like to use blocks (`\begin{block}…\end{block}`). These blocks are rendered slightly too wide to fit into my theme. Is there a way how I can set the default width of blocks, e.g. to `.9\textwidth`?

Comment: The question has been answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-latex-beamer

Comment: I'd suggest self-answering this so that it gets out of the "unanswered" bin. Otherwise, people may visit the page to suggest something, only to find that it's already handled.

Comment: The question has been answered on [LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12550/changing-default-width-of-blocks-in-latex-beamer).